# Format JSON Payload for Multiple Arrays

Tags: json, mule, session-variables, dataweave, mule-esb

I need to format an incoming payload JSON to a certain manner. The sample payload JSON is given below.

```
[
  {
    "value": {
      "States": [
        {
          "Name": "New South Wales",
          "Code": "NSW"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "States": [
        {
          "Name": "Western Australia",
          "Code": "WA"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The output that I'm trying to get to is given below:

```
[
  {
    "SystemCode": "STATE",
    "Name": "StateName",
    "Code": "NSW"
  },
  {
    "SystemCode": "STATE",
    "Name": "StateName",
    "Code": "WA"
  }
]
```

As you can see above, in the output, **SystemCode** and **Name** will remain constant, whereas the **Code** value will change as per the incoming payload. Once the required output is generated, I need to store the same as a JSON in a session variable. How can I achieve this in **Mule dataweave 1.0**
Please note that I can receive multiple arrays as payload with different codes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var codes = payload..Code

%var baseObj = {
    "SystemCode" : "STATE",
    "Name"       : "StateName"
}
---
codes map (baseObj ++ {"Code": $})
```

To set it to a session var:

```
<dw:transform-message>
  <dw:set-session-variable variableName="sessionVarName">
    <![CDATA[
      <YOUR CODE HERE>
    ]]>
  </dw:set-session-variable>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I get this error while executing.

Type mismatch for 'flatten' operator
     found :null
  required :array

Comment: Could you also let me know how the flatten works for the below array:

"Codes": [
                    {
                        "CodeValue": "TRA"
                    },
                    {
                        "CodeValue": "MED"
                    }

Comment: Actually you shouldn't even need flatten. Try my edited version, it uses the descendants selector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-selectors#descendants-selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.value.States map 
{
    "SystemCode": "STATE",
    "Name": "StateName",
    "Code": $.Code[0]
}
```